# oracle longops completed still job running any suggestions for that?

Tags: oracle, performance

My oracle merge statement is running longer than expected. I can see all longs ops completed 100% and RBS segment Block Used =1 only but still statement is keep running, Please suggest where and what to look in oracle(toad)

Comment: Is it a single node or multi-node RAC env? You might be looking a wrong node. Try using 'gv$..' select * from gv$session_longops where time_remaining > 0;

Comment: it is running in parallel and now there is no longops showing, they have been gone and still merge statement is running

Comment: Is your MERGE inside a pl-sql (begin .. end;) block or loop? If yes, hit '/' and see if takes you to SQL prompt.